# Creating buttons or front page for VBA word

Tags: vba, ms-word

Just a quick question. Is there a way to create a front page as a dashboard with buttons in word to assign to the macros created?

I have to paste the code in every word sheet I open each time I want to run it.

I would like to open a word sheet of my choice and the modules to be exported into that sheet each time where I can run them by aid of buttons.

Comment: Why is this in Word? Excel is a better choice for making dashboards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Place your Code (`Modules` and `Userforms`) into the `Normal` Project, if not in there already. If they are not there already then drag each `Module` and `Userform` from your current Project to the `Normal` Project.

Then in the `Normal Project` select the following:

> Microsoft Word Objects > ThisDocument

The Select `Document` as your Object and then New as your `Procedure`.

Then in the `Document_New` `Sub` Call your "DashBoard" or the Macro which initialises your code and bring up the first `Userform`.

[image]

---

```
 Private Sub Document_Open()
    'When you open an Existing Word Document
    MsgBox "This Worked"
    Call SomeMacro
 End Sub
```

---

```
 Private Sub Document_New()
   'When you open a New Word Document with Word already Open
   MsgBox "This Worked"
   Call SomeMacro
 End Sub
```

**Note:** This will only auto run the Macro when you open a Word Document that exists already. It will not work if you open Word using the Application Button as found in the Start Menu > Programs >Microsoft Office.

**EDIT:**

To run a macro if the Word Application has been Executed (Started from the Microsoft Word Application Button) then have a macro in the `Normal` project  named `AutoExec`.

```
Sub AutoExec()

MsgBox "This Messages Appears Every time"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much guys,Really do appreciate the help.Unfortunately I cannot use Excel as I am removing duplicates of a very high volume in a word document and have perfected everything except for the user form.